# Is there any way to export custom relationship?

Tags: sugarcrm

I have made custom relationships between modules. when i am trying to export the data All of the other module data has come across okay but the relationship data does not seem to be importable.

Is there any way to do this ?

Comment: Do you have an direct access to SugarCRM database?

Comment: yes i have direct access

Comment: So you can grab data from join table(s). For example, records in Contacts module joined with Accounts' ones with accounts_contacts table. Skim over files like cache/modules/<MODULE_NAME>/<MODULE_NAME>vardefs.php to get names of join tables for your custom modules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can, but not by using SugarCRM itself.

By using [Talend Open Studio](http://www.talend.com/products/talend-open-studio) you can talk to the other tables in the SugarCRM database.

I use both the Talend supplied component and a third party component from [cloudbee.com](http://cloudbee.com/sugar-crm-talend-component/).